# Google Maps API - Error page but nothing in console

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We have a google maps api driven page. It works on our production server but not on what is slated to be our new dev and production boxes.

```
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. 
See the JavaScript console for technical details.
```

I would say that this is related to the API key but our API key is there... and when I check the javascript console, nothing is there.

Any ideas on how I go about tracking this down if nothing is being spit out to the browser/javascript console?

Comment: Does the API key you're using correspond to your new dev/production box domains?

Comment: I was just doing some more research and it looks like the key needs to be unique from domain to domain. I assume this also means internal domain/computer names. Is this what you're getting at?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the **box** it has to do with the **domain**. You can created a wildcard key like `*.myproductiondomain.com` and then point `dev.myproductiondomain.com` to your dev site, probably via a hosts file. And then you can use the same key, if you wish.

Comment: Hrm... the new boxes aren't visible on the web yet. But we are testing them internally remotely... like this: http://pcname/Folder/OurMapPage.aspx. When debugging locally inside of visual studio, it works. Hrmmm....

Comment: They don't have to be visible on the web, but if you're accessing them through a browser, then it has to be via a **domain** - in this case, `pcname` appears to be the domain. If you don't have an API Key for the `pcname` domain, then it won't work.

Comment: Pop that up as an answer because I just verified that about the same time you responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you API Key is valid for the domain you are accessing your maps page from.

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarification for anyone who follows, if you access the machine you're running the map on like this: http://machinename/Page.aspx, it thinkgs <machinename> is a domain.

Comment: If you hold a account with Google you can add these domains to the site list which are supposed to use that API key instead of generating API for each domain